# Prevent multiple submit button clicks in ASP.NET without jQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to prevent multiple submits when a user clicks a link button multiple times, but do not want to use jQuery. Ideally, I would like to do this in code behind.

My current solution is based on [This Code Project Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/107373/Stopping-the-multiple-postbacks-of-ASP-NET-linkbut)

Currently I have this:

```
    private const string _disableButtonScript = "return disableButton(this.id);";

    /// <summary>
    /// Prevents a button being clicked multiple times on the client
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="currentPage">The page the button resides on</param>
    /// <param name="button">The button to prevent the multiple clicks on</param>
    public void PreventMultipleClientClickPostbacks(Page currentPage, LinkButton button)
    {
        if (currentPage.IsPostBack || currentPage.IsCallback)
        {
            // Already added script
            return;
        }

        AddDisableScriptToPageHeader(currentPage, button);

        string currentOnClick = string.Empty;

        // If onclick already exist we need to append to it
        if (button.Attributes["onclick"] != null)
        {
            currentOnClick = button.Attributes["onclick"];

            // Remove current onclick
            button.Attributes.Remove("onclick");

            if (!currentOnClick.EndsWith(";"))
            {
                // add semi colon suffix
                currentOnClick = currentOnClick + ";";
            }
        }

        // add client onclick handler
        button.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("{0}{1}", currentOnClick, _disableButtonScript));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the javascript disable function to the page header
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="currentPage">The page to add the header script to</param>
    /// <param name="button">The button to add the script to</param>
    private static void AddDisableScriptToPageHeader(Page currentPage, Control button)
    {
        // Generate disable script
        StringBuilder scriptLinkHtml = new StringBuilder();
        scriptLinkHtml.AppendLine("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        scriptLinkHtml.AppendLine("//<![CDATA[");
        scriptLinkHtml.AppendLine("var callCount = 0;");
        scriptLinkHtml.AppendLine("function disableButton(btnId) {");
        scriptLinkHtml.AppendLine("var ret = true;");
        scriptLinkHtml.AppendLine("var ele = document.getElementById(btnId);");
        scriptLinkHtml.AppendLine("if (ele != null && !ele.disabled)");
        scriptLinkHtml.AppendLine("ret = true;");
        scriptLinkHtml.AppendLine("else");
        scriptLinkHtml.AppendLine("ret = false;");
        scriptLinkHtml.AppendLine("if (ele != null)");
        scriptLinkHtml.AppendLine("ele.disabled = true;");
        scriptLinkHtml.AppendLine("return ret;");
        scriptLinkHtml.AppendLine("}");
        scriptLinkHtml.AppendLine("//]]>");
        scriptLinkHtml.AppendLine("</script>");

        // Add script link to page header
        LiteralControl scriptLink = new LiteralControl(scriptLinkHtml.ToString());
        scriptLink.ID = "disableButtonScript";
        currentPage.Header.Controls.Add(scriptLink);
    }
```

This renders out on the client like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
function disableButton(btnId) {
var ret = true;
var ele = document.getElementById(btnId);
if (ele != null && !ele.disabled)
ret = true;
else
ret = false;
if (ele != null)
ele.disabled = true;
return ret;
}
</script>

<a onclick="javascript:return disableButton(this.id);" id="cntMain_btnSubmit" class="but-yellow frcr" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$cntMain$btnSubmit&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">Add Note</a>
```

This works nicely in FireFox & Chrome. However it only disabled the button in IE, and did not submit at all.

To get the submission to work in IE I had to add

```
currentPage.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(new PostBackOptions(button))
```

Into the javascript, which makes it work as desired in IE, but now submits on every click in Firefox & Chrome.

Can anyone suggest a fix or an alternative?

Comment: Why you doing it server side ? You can do the same in simple javascript and without jQuery.

Comment: I want to add it to a library that can be used by multiple web apps

Answer (score -1):

I'd try it with a boolean flag which should work like this:

```
private bool _clicked;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

      _clicked = false;
}


protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
if(!_clicked){
_clicked = true;
}
```